# Android: Check inside a service for internet connectivity, and wait until internet connectivity is established

Tags: android, service

```
public class FBPost extends Service{

        private Bundle params = new Bundle();
        private String userID="";

        String response;

        public void onCreate(String userID,String name)
        {
            super.onCreate();
            params.putString("message", "Test " + new Date().toLocaleString() );
            params.putString("caption", "Hey there");
            this.userID=userID;
        }


        @Override
        public int onStartCommand( Intent intent , int flags , int startId )
        {
            if(checkInternetConnection())
            {
                fb_post();
            return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                 BroadcastReceiver connec_recv= new BroadcastReceiver() {

                     @Override
                     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                         if(checkInternetConnection())
                             fb_post();
                         } 
                 };

                 final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                 intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
                 registerReceiver(connec_recv, intentFilter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

         private boolean checkInternetConnection() {
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                // test for connection
                if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                        && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                        && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                     try{
                            URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");
                            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
                            in.close();
                            return true;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            return false;
                        }
                }
                    return false;
            }

         private void fb_post()
         {
            //MORE CODE
         }


}
```

what if there's still no internet conectivity? Should i just call another instance of the same service from the broadcast receiver instead of fb_post()? Can I make a service wait()  and then notify() every time a connectivity broadcast receiver recieves a connection change broadcast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the right way to implement this kind of functionality is as follows:

- If there is no connection - give up the `Service`, register a `BroadcastReceiver` to listen for connection changes and save a flag somewhere (`SharedPreferences` for example) telling that there is work left to do
- When the connection is established and your flag is `true` - start the `Service` again and do the job

Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, kinda forgot about my question. So, cant I just call the service again in the broadcast receiver? But I can only have one instance of a service, so does that mean no other FBPosts can go through until this one's done? Or would I get a service leak?

Comment: @Anmol, You should stop the service if there is no connectivity and you can't accomplish the task. There is no sense of running it further.